# Snowflake UI sessions are not killed after 4 hours

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know that there is user parameter [CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive), which defines wether session should stay alive forever or be killed after 4 hours of inactivity.

Mine is set to `False`.

```
show parameters like 'CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE';
```

But in Snowflake UI on tab Account > Sessions I see my old session, which started almost 2 days ago.

When I check this session in `QUERY_HISTORY` table, I also see that there were no queries for almost 2 days.

Why my session is not getting killed? Which settings should I change?

---

If there is no way to kill such sessions automatically, then I'd like to kill them manually using `select system$abort_session(<session_id>);` command.

In order to do that, first of all I need to get list of active sessions, that I see on UI tab Account > Sessions.

Is there any system table/view which can provide such data?

Answer (score 2):

Per the Snowflake Documentation, the `CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE` is only for ODBC, JDBC, Python, and Node.JS client connectors.  It does not affect the UI.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#client-session-keep-alive

Comment: Does it mean that UI sessions will be alive forever? Or until user closes the browser.

Comment: I've tried looking for this answer before (specific to UI Web client timeouts) and in the past, I have been told the token associated with the session becomes invalid after 4 hours although the session can remain open.  It is a popular feature request for the idle session timeout to be configurable but it is not today.